# How to cleanup overlay2 docker

Tags: linux, docker

I got some docker containers running on linux machine, the /docker/overlay2 folder grows very fast in disk size. Due to which we are not able to push new images

When I check inside overlay2 i find it contains very old layers ( Aug 2019)

I tried following command to cleanup
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm
docker rm -v $(sudo docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
docker system prune

But reclaimed 0B

Also checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672001/is-it-safe-to-clean-docker-overlay2

https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

https://success.docker.com/article/error-message-no-space-left-on-device-in-default-machine

What is the best way to clean this?

---

**docker logs**

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
```

Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.

Waiting for DB to start

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Jul 14 05:04:23 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
DB started
/opt/ion/platform/daemon/DM_DOCKER /
Launched daemon from /opt/ion/platform/daemon/DM_DOCKER/mkvd118p1.lx
Waiting for port 13000
bash: connect: Network is unreachable
bash: /dev/tcp/localhost/13000: Network is unreachable
Deamon started on port 13000
/
Executing : /startup/ansible_container_startup.sh
Executing : /startup/cups_startup.sh
Executing : /startup/samba_startup.sh
Executing : /startup/start_check_mk_agent.sh

**docker diff**
Error response from daemon: mkdir /docker/overlay2/f033daa6d065ff85484b54fcd9a7786f839917d180129ea8fed0f627ad776095-init/merged: no space left on device

[docker ps -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifugv.png)

[docker volume ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsW7t.png)

[docker images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYOvd.png)

Comment: Do you have containers running? What images do they use, what images are not being cleaned up? How many logs do those containers generate (`docker logs`)? How many files are changed by those containers (`docker diff`)?

Comment: We have 1 image and container running only. No other images are their. Docker logs and docker diff added to question

Comment: Please provide the output of `docker ps -a`, `docker images` and `docker volume ls`.

Comment: Added output to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Please add it as text. Just put three backticks before and after each text block to properly format it.

Answer (score 2):

The typical answer for most people when overlay2 is too large is to run a cleanup, pruning stopped containers and images that have been untagged (replaced with a newer tag). That's done with `docker prune` and there are other options to that command to prune more data. For more details on cleaning this folder in general, see "[Is it safe to clean docker/overlay2/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672068/596285)".

If the issue was the `/var/lib/docker/containers` folder growing, I would suspect logs written to stdout/stderr, and there are [various ways to clean that and prevent excessive logs in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510314/596285).

However, for this issue, if the overlay2 folder rapidly increases in size when you start a container, that container is most likely writing to the read/write filesystem associated with that container. Every modification to a file triggers a copy-on-write to the container specific layer. You can diagnose which files are being created or modified with `docker container diff` on the specific container id. In your situation, it appears that is happening fast enough to fill your drive so your machine may not have the capacity to debug or run this container, so you may be forced to debug this on a machine with more capacity.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `docker image prune -a` to remove useless images.

Comment: Explaining how you got from the question that was asked to Docker Images would make this a better and more clear answer.

Comment: This sadly does not fully clean up. For some reason overlay2 still has plenty of old data, even if there are 0 images.